# css list menu child selector on hover

Tags: css, list, css-selectors

I've a problem with my css,

I've a list menu, I use a child selector to create a gap at one area of the menu,

However, on hover, the background color it's taking a full width . . .. only on the element selected by child, I don't manage to fix it, if anybody can give me hand ?

You can see it live here ( it's the Press center section in the menu): http://thibaultrolando.com/vinacotheque/new_home/
Here is my css:

```
.nav-menu{
border-top:2px solid #7f683e;

border-bottom:2px solid #7f683e;
}

.nav-menu li a
{
color:black !important;
display:block;
font-family:HelveticaCE-Cond;
font-size:20px;
font-style:normal!important;
line-height:1;
margin-left:auto!important;
margin-right:auto!important;
padding:15px 13px!important;
width:100%!important;
}

.nav-menu li:last-child a

{
border-right:none!important;
color:black !important;;
display:block;
font-size:20px;
font-style:normal!important;
line-height:1;
padding:15px 0px!important;
  }
.nav-menu li:nth-child(4) a:hover > a,.nav-menu li:nth-child(4) a:hover
{
border-right:none!important;
margin-left:365px !important;
color:white !important;
font-size:20px;
font-style:normal!important;
line-height:1;
background-color:#7f683e;
padding:15px 13px!important;
}

.nav-menu li:nth-child(4) a
{
border-right:none!important;
margin-left:365px !important;
color:black !important;;
font-size:20px;
font-style:normal!important;
line-height:1;
padding:15px 13px!important;
}

.navigation a:hover
{transition:0.6s ease 0s;
background-color:#812545;
color:black !important;
margin-left:auto!important;
margin-right:auto!important;
padding:none!important;
width:100%!important;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > a,.nav-menu li a:hover

{
background-color:#7f683e;
color:white !important;
margin-left:auto!important;
margin-right:auto!important;
padding:none!important;
width:100%!important;
}
.nav-menu {
margin-top:-60px;
 } 
.nav-menu .current_page_item > a,.nav-menu .current_page_ancestor > a,.nav-menu     .current-menu-item > a,.nav-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a
{
color:#bc360a;
font-style:none!important;
}
```

thank you so myuch :)

Comment: That's a lot of `!important`

Comment: Not to answer your question, but something is going wrong if you have to use `!important` like that.

Comment: I use a child theme, main of the ime the css doesnt change on my child css if I dont put this :s

Comment: It's probably the order of the CSS then. If the child theme CSS is being loaded first and then the main parent one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution here is, thankfully, to simplify your CSS.

1. Remove the rule `.nav-menu li:nth-child(4) a:hover > a,.nav-menu li:nth-child(4) a:hover`
2. Remove the right-padding of 40px on `#menu-menu` (it's not in your sample above, but it's in the stylesheet when I hit your web site)
3. Change `.nav-menu li:nth-child(4) a` to `.nav-menu li:nth-of-type(4)`

It's true that your css is not the best that it could be. You'll still have several issues after you make the above changes. I recommend you do the following:

- Apply hover effects to the `li` elements only, not the anchor elements.
- avoid applying special padding and margin to particular items. Your design necessitates using special padding for the 4th item, which is fine, but avoid it elsewhere (like the right-padding in the `ul`).

Comment: awesome, thank you so much for all the recommendation :)

Comment: Absolutely, any time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the background to be the intended width, as you can see [here](http://cl.ly/image/1g0J3n0A0d0L), but I had to hide your logo in order to do so. To make this element the intended width I had to remove this line of CSS.

```
    .nav-menu li:nth-child(4) a:hover > a, .nav-menu li:nth-child(4) a:hover {
            margin-left: 365px !important;
     }
```

On another note, it looks like you have some overall structural issues. If I were building a navigation bar with a logo in the middle of it I would just use a whole unordered list with the logo as the center list item. Rather then having a whole navigation bar structure and positioning a logo over it. Kind of like this [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/maxrbaldwin/r4efY/). Kind of a rough mock up, but you get the point. Feel free to reach out with any questions.